# Do xaml animations block the main thread?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, xaml, animation

Do the xaml animations block the main thread? I'm showing a big grid with lots of data and several animations and even with everything (but the property changes) on background threads the UI is far from being smooth.

As I have several Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (and some Invoke when needed) I was thinking that maybe the animations make the invokes to go slower. Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything that writes to the UI has to be on the main thread.  You may just have contention for CPU slowing everything down.  Check CPU with Task Manager.  To my knowledge animation does not block the main thread.

Comment: Mmmm ... maybe related with GPU? In a desktop works more or less fine, on a virtual server connected thru remote desktop its on its knees.

Comment: SoMoS I you should have mentioned this is remote.  RDP protocol is not great for animation- try watching a YouTube video over the same link :-)

Comment: I accept to see 'broken' animations, not to have wrong performance. Videos are badly viewed but they reproduce at their normal speed, my application does everything much slower.

Comment: Even the background threads have to get in line on the main thread for the callback and if the main thread is is lagging then the call backs will be lagging.  And calls to the background will be lagging.  Like Chris said need to profile but I suspect you the core background process is running fine it just is the calls and call backs that are slowed down by a animation over RDP.

Comment: Don't forget that `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` still uses the UI thread, so operations that are running asynchronously on the dispatcher can still cause performance problems because they are still running on the main UI thread. I always recommend using a separate thread entirely for background processes that don't involve the UI.

Comment: I think that the key problem is the virtualized server with Virtuosso. The software renderer probably is far from being optimized. Is a virtualized OS for servers so it must be the latest priority ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend investing in a profiler.  Certainly, animations run on the UI thread and heavy use of animations might be the cause of the choppiness, but there is no way for us to know for sure.

My preference for profiling C# is [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), but there are tons of others out there.  There are even WPF-specific diagnostic tools from Microsoft in the [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx?ppud=4), but I haven't tried them.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking on profiling the application but I'm not sure on how to view the animation load as they are pure xaml code ... I will take a look at the recommended suite.

Comment: Using the starndard VS2010 profiler I can see that the botleneck is on a Dispatcher.Invoke call but I cannot see why the main UI is blocked.

Comment: That's usually a sign that a background thread is Invoking to the UI too frequently (for example, if you are running a timer on a background thread and with each tick doing something on the UI).  What's the upstream caller of that?  Can you reduce the frequency or the amount of work it does on each call?

Comment: I think that it's more likely the main UI thread is blocked with something else (like animations or anything else) than too much calls. The Invokes are due to PropertyChanged notifications on timers, right (and they're needed but not too many of them)

Comment: You were right. Under certain circumstances a big amount of information was loaded and a property changed event was generated for each one of the items loaded. Thanks! Just to let you know, Perforator  didn't work well on my system but built-in profiler did the job.